# Pulling force of magnetic field on a magnetic object

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I found some equations (http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/force.html) to calculate a pulling force from a magnet.

F = 0.5 * χ * μ0 * v * (∂H2/∂l) and F = Fm^2 * μ0 * A / (2*g^2)

The problem, I have with these equations is that they seem to be wrong. If l or g (distance) -> 0 (and already at not unreasonably small scales), the force becomes infinite or super high. This is not possible. Is there a better equation?

Comment: What do you mean by "already at not unreasonably small scales"?

Comment: mm range is sufficient to get values like 1000N for 13 windings and 500A

Comment: for stuff in 10^-5m² range.

Comment: 500A is quite a lot of current. If your coil has a resistance of 10 ohms (which, as far as I can tell, is not an uncommon value), then you're heating your solenoid with 2.5 megawatts of power (for reference, most microwave ovens have a power output of about 1 kilowatt). Also, 1 kN is not actually all that much - it's enough to lift about 100 kg off the ground, which is not uncommon for industrial solenoids.

Comment: Too hard to read (better to typeset formulas in TeX). But only holding power is reasonably easy to calculate. For other situations, there is simulation software.

Comment: I am sceptical because the result becomes infinite if you go down and down.

Comment: @dgrat In any practical application, your gap $g$ is always going to be greater than zero - even when the surfaces are "touching," there is still a finite average gap due to the surfaces not being perfectly smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If l or g (distance) -> 0 (and already at not unreasonably small
>   scales), the force becomes infinite or super high.

You are right - this formula can be used only, when the gap is long enough so that its reluctance is much greater than the reluctance of the rest of the magnetic circuit. Under this assumption, practically all magnetomotive force, $F_m$, is applied to the gap, so we can express magnetic field as $B=\frac {F_m\mu_0} g$.

As the gap shrinks, its reluctance decreases and becomes comparable and, at some point, even lower than the reluctance of the rest of the magnetic circuit. As a result, the above assumption and the formula, based on it, become invalid.

> Is there a better equation?

The equation which does not depend on the length of the gap is $F=\frac {B^2 A} {2\mu_0}$.

Comment: So if the force becomes bigger than in the equation from you, one has to swap.

Comment: @dgrat That's one way to decide which equation to use, if you can make that comparison. The equation without the gap is actually presented (and derived) in the same article. It is replaced by the equation with the gap, because the latter could be simpler to use.